# .Net 6 Error on creation of TSQL trigger in Migration

Tags: t-sql, .net-6.0

Has anyone got a clue on how to address the following issue?

When attempting to update a database via migration I get the following error:

```
An explicit value for the identity column in table 'HistoryUsers' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.
```

Running the trigger in Management studio works!

The code giving the error:

```
 migrationBuilder.Sql(@"
    CREATE TRIGGER [Users_TRIGGER]
    ON [Users]
    AFTER UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE
    AS
    DECLARE @EmpID int, @user nvarchar(max), @activity nvarchar(200);
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
    BEGIN
        SET @activity = 'UPDATE';
        SET @user = SYSTEM_USER;
        INSERT INTO [HistoryUsers]
        SELECT *, @activity, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @user
        FROM inserted
    END
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)
    BEGIN
        SET @activity = 'INSERT';
        SET @user = SYSTEM_USER;
        INSERT INTO [HistoryUsers]
        SELECT *, @activity, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @user
        FROM inserted
    END
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted) AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted)
    BEGIN 
        SET @activity = 'DELETE';
        SET @user = SYSTEM_USER;
        INSERT INTO [HistoryUsers]
        SELECT *, @activity, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @user
        FROM deleted
    END
    GO
");
```

Comment: If you include a column list, which you should be doing anyway, do you get the error?

Comment: Just found out the issue add to not use the Key column, e.g.:

````
...  
SELECT inserted.FirstName, inserted.LastName, inserted.Email, inserted.APIkey, inserted.UserTypeId, @activity, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @user
  FROM inserted
``` 

becomes 

```
SELECT *, @activity, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @user
  FROM inserted
```

Comment: I think that's what you're referring to Larnu. Thank you.

Comment: No, that's probably worse. I mean define the column list in the `INSERT` clause.

Comment: Aside: You might want to contemplate using `else` rather than just `if`. Your first test checks for an `update`, i.e. both `inserted` and `deleted` are populated. By following that with an `else` you can check either table to see if it is empty to determine whether an `insert` or `delete` fired the trigger. Another `else` handles the last possibility. As a rule you should set logging triggers to fire last using [`sp_settriggerorder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-settriggerorder-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback this can be closed as the issue was addressed.
Thanks.